# Beautiful Tikz for Thank you

Tags: beamer, slideshow

my friends, I wanna put a beautiful thank you figure in beamer slides. What is your idea about "thank you" figures by tikz?

Comment: Either use ornaments or the tikzduck package.

Comment: Just say the words and do nothing fancy at all. It isn't magic you're trying to sell.

Answer (score 7):

IMHO: I would not do a thank you slide, rather have a good summary/outlook slide as the last slide that will be visible during questions so people have time to read it again if they like.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \duck[speech={Thanks!}]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you keep your summary short (as you should) there should be room for a TikZduck saying "thanks" as well